# Spark: subtract values in same DataSet row

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given the following dataset:

```
| title | start | end
| bla   | 10    | 30
```

I would like to find the difference (start - end) between the two numbers and set them into a new column, so that it looks like:

```
| title | time_spent |
 | bla   | 20 |
```

The data is of type `Dataset<Row>`
`dataset = dataset.withColumn("millis spent: ", col("end") - col("start")).as("Time spent");`
I expected this to work, as i saw in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46334705/subtract-two-columns-with-null-in-spark-dataframe) question, but it does ot, maybe because that thread is about DataFrames and not DataSets, or maybe because Scala allows it where as in Java is illegal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider static methods. In short:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr;
...
df = df
    .withColumn("time_spent", expr("end - start"))
    .drop("start")
    .drop("end");
```

`expr()` will evaluate the value in your columns.

Here is the full example with the right imports. Sorry the bulk part of the example is about creating the dataframe.

```
package net.jgp.books.sparkInAction.ch12.lab990Others;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

/**
 * Use of expr().
 * 
 * @author jgp
 */
public class ExprApp {

  /**
   * main() is your entry point to the application.
   * 
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExprApp app = new ExprApp();
    app.start();
  }

  /**
   * The processing code.
   */
  private void start() {
    // Creates a session on a local master
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("All joins!")
        .master("local")
        .getOrCreate();

    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
        DataTypes.createStructField(
            "title",
            DataTypes.StringType,
            false),
        DataTypes.createStructField(
            "start",
            DataTypes.IntegerType,
            false),
        DataTypes.createStructField(
            "end",
            DataTypes.IntegerType,
            false) });

    List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
    rows.add(RowFactory.create("bla", 10, 30));
    Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
    df.show();

    df = df
        .withColumn("time_spent", expr("end - start"))
        .drop("start")
        .drop("end");
    df.show();

  }
}
```

Comment: `expr("....")` is the method i needed, that `functions.*` package definetly deserves some deep study.

Comment: Ok, nasty plug for my book "Spark in Action, 2e" (http://jgp.net/sia), but i am working a full appendix as a reference for those awesome functions :). They are so under values (I think).